# what is brown out time in micro controller and how to use it?

Tags: hardware, microcontroller, avr, pic

I want to write error info to eeprom/flash after detecting the low input power.Basically i want to log the under voltage and over voltage error scenarios to non volatile memory.

I came to know about some of the implementations using the brow out reset circuit. It wold be really helpful if i get some pointers on this.

Comment: What exactly is your question? It is not clear to me.

Comment: My aim is to write the some error info into the flash/eeprom of the micro controller before the micro Controller shuts down because of Under Voltage or Over voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Example for AVR and PIC:

when the BOD detects the under-voltage, the MCU will reset and it's already too late to log somethinng. You cannot save the state before the reset. The solution is to read `MCUSR` (for AVR) or `RCON` (for PIC) at startup and to find the reset source. Then you can log the event in non volatile memory (but you will log the restart date, not the stop date).

Comment: Thanks Julien, Is their a way to detect the Under Voltage and Log the Same to non volatile memory ? I want to log voltage, current and some program variables to flash when under voltage happens. One way is to use external hold up capacitors so that controller will be functional for small duration after the Under Voltage event Occurs.

Comment: Suggest me if any efficient methods available.

Comment: @user2857290 My suggestion was for low power automated detection with existing HW peripheral. You could of course measure the supply voltage using a dedicated ADC or add an external comparator (a little above BOD threshold level) to log before reset. For external HW detection circuitry, the electronic stackexchange may be better suited for your question.

Comment: Note that any "hold" circuitry will have a severe problem with the fact that the MCU will typically draw a much higher current than normal when writing to EEPROM or flash as a "last gasp".